All Logs written in /dev/null
I have a few Server hosted by x and y. How can Id deactivate anything about logs. I will connect via a VPN Service like OpenVPN or Wireguard. Also I want to connect to the Server with SSH. On this server should no IPs and anything like this anywhere logged. How can I either deactivate or write it directly to /dev/null. So it is to 99,99% not to see how and which IP has

certainly nothing at all malicious is going on here.

Hi! Aside from your question really sounding extremely ominous, it's too broad. A lot of things log. And they log differently. Without even knowing what things you're running, this is impossible to answer. Also, not sure I'd want to be part of whatever it is that you're doing. Also, if you think your hoster doesn't log connections to SSH, um, what do you think is their job? They run the network for your server…

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you wish to deny the log information to yourself in a server you have root access to, you should be free to do so: you could stop any logging and auditing services and link any remaining logs to /dev/null.
Since you did not provide the OS version nor any information of your setups, it will be impossible to provide exact details.
Note that if you are granted root access to a hosted server, you (as the customer of the hosting provider) will be held responsible of whatever happens within the server anyway in some significant degree: see your hosting agreement and the laws and regulations of the applicable jurisdiction.
However, the hosting provider can still independently log the IP addresses that are connecting to "your" servers: they can do this e.g. in a hardware firewall device located between the hosted servers and the internet, and/or in the authentication server that controls access to the servers they're renting to you. Unless the hosting provider has done something exceedingly stupid, you won't have any kind of command access to that part of their infrastructure.
